# Find Matrix Data based on Index Value

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, lookup

I need to create an array (list) or matrix that functions as a key:value pair and allows me to lookup information about a company.

Python doesn't seem to support 2d arrays, so I am using a Matrix instead.

```
Matrix = {}

Matrix[1,1] = '1'
Matrix[1,2] = 'Dog Company'
Matrix[1,3] = '0'
Matrix[1,4] = '../../img/dogcompany_logo.png'
```

My python script uses this data to build a static HTML file based on the entered company name.

I need to write a function that returns the row index of of a specified company name and uses that index to get the value of another column within that row.

Each company has a unique name so there should only be one row index containing the specified company name.

For example:

```
[pseudo-code]
def rowIndex(companyName):

    for x in range(1, Matrix.length):
        if Matrix[x,2] = companyName:
            return x

myIndex = rowIndex('Dog Company')
logoURL = Matrix[myIndex,4]
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can help me get this to work or provide a better solution.

Comment: Python definitely has multidimensional lists - use a dictionary, and the key is the company name, and namedtuple as value

Comment: A list of dicts or a database maybe?

Comment: What do the other values mean? `Matrix[1,1]='1'` / `Matrix[1,3]='0'`? When you mention key-value, I immediately think of dictionaries; is there a restriction on using dictionaries?

Comment: A pandas DataFrame would probably suit your needs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: If each "row" has to do with the data of a company, why not have a simple dict with key the company name and value whatever else you want?

Comment: musikreck, [1,1] (showName) and [1,3] (showLogo) are bools indicating whether the company name and logo should be displayed or hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you are storing, but you can use this. But if you want long term persistance, use a database or a json file

```
from collections import namedtuple

Company = namedtuple('Company', 'info1 info2')
companies = {"Dog Company" : Company("Data for info1", "Data for info2")}

def get_company(company):
   if company in companies:
      return companies[company]
   return None

get_company("Dog Company")
```

Comment: Interesting. It needs to return a specific info value but the line return companies[company] will give info1 and info2. What if I just wanted info1?

Comment: company = get_company("Dog Company"); info1 = company.info1.  NamedTuples are created into a class, though can not be modified after instantiating.  If you need to modify, instead of a namedtuple, you can create a class: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Worked like a charm, Geoff.   Thanks!